# How to navigate from one component to another by clicking a button using React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to use `react-router-dom` to navigate my website. 
Every component will render `<button>` whenever `onClick` will active the switch to the next component.

Main component `Login.js` will contain all the 4 components inside it.
I need to know what are the ways to do it.
(The first time user must not skip the login process **below** anyhow)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';
        import MobileNum from './MobileNum.jsx';
        import IdNumber from './IdNum.jsx';
        import userEmail from './userEmail';
        import CreatePass from './createPassword .jsx';

        class Login extends Component {
       render() {
        return (
          <div>
           <button  onClick={}></button>
          </div>
        );
      }
     }
```

Comment: so these will be shown only if logged in?

Comment: @Apostolos This is the first screen the user will have if he hasn't sign up yet.

Comment: do you really need routers? i guess a show/hide based on step would be enough

Comment: @Apostolos First it must be secured, second what is 'based on step' ? I rather navigate with router.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect the user you want to call `push` on the [history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) object. To get the history object in a class component you can use the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) higher-order component, e.g.

```
class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    const { history } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
       <button onClick={() => history.push('foo')}>Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const LoginWithRouter = withRouter(Login);
```

Source: https://dev.to/kozakrisz/react-router---how-to-pass-history-object-to-a-component-3l0j

Comment: Hi Justin and thanks. I want to push a <component> not an address of a component, the user must not be able to echange the url manually in the address bar.

Comment: “I want to push a <component> not an address of a component” that’s just not how react-router works.  You need to configure your <Route/>s to load the correct content for each page based on the URL address.  Then you navigate with react-router by changing the URL.